# Struct in C throwing a segment fault (core dumped)

Tags: c

Sorry in advance since the code isn't entirely in English, not my first language.
Also sorry, my writing is a little bit messy.
When trying to pass data from a file to a struct that will store the info from each line of the file, I am met with a Segment Fault (core dumped).
Also the file is structured, so there isn't different input from different lines.
Is there any way I can use memory allocation with a struct?

EDIT:First of all, thanks for the help so far. So, after some testing found the origin of the segment fault (core dumped), but I can't comprehend it, it seems to be generated by trying to open a file with the name given by a variable. It was written just as a example, which uses a variable, in a C book I have. Any clue what is wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct tipo
{
    int div_1;
    int div_2;
    int div_3;
    int div_4;
    long int cc;
    char nome [60];
    char morada [60];
    int porta;
    char postal [8];
 }  potato;

void read_file (FILE *fp, potato *tipo)
{
    char name[20];
    int w;
    int i;
    printf("Pretende abrir o base.txt?\n");
    printf("Se sim, escreva 1.\n");


  printf("Caso contrário, escreva 0\n");
    scanf(" %d ", &w);
    if(w)
    {
        fp = fopen("base.txt", "r+");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Indique o nome do ficheiro que pretende abrir: \n");
        scanf(" %s ", name);
        fp = fopen(name, "r+");
    }
    for(i=0;i<EOF;i++)
    {
        getInfo(tipo, fp, i);
    }
        fclose(fp);
}

void getInfo(potato *tipo, FILE *fp, int i) //Auxiliary function
{
    fscanf(fp,"%d.%d.%d.%d",tipo[i].div_1, tipo[i].div_2, tipo[i].div_3, tipo[i].div_4);
    fscanf(fp," %ld ", &tipo[i].cc);
    fgets(tipo[i].nome, 60, fp);
    fgets(tipo[i].morada, 60, fp);
    fscanf(fp," %d ", &tipo[i].porta);
    fgets(tipo[i].postal, 60, fp);
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). One of possible reasons is unchecked file open failure. NOTE: `EOF` is an negative value, so `getInfo()` won't be called from `read_file()` and `tipo` passed to `read_file()` won't be used, so passing invalid pointer to that won't cause Segmentation Fault.

Comment: `postal` is an array of size 8 but you tell `fgets` that it's of size 60: `fgets(tipo[i].postal, 60, fp);`. Also, you've missed ampersands in `fscanf(fp,"%d.%d.%d.%d",tipo[i].div_1, tipo[i].div_2, tipo[i].div_3, tipo[i].div_4);`

Comment: In order to help you debug your code, we need a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: However, I have trouble believing that your problem has anything to do with `struct tipo`, because the code presented will never call `getInfo()`.  The `for` loop will always terminate without performing any iterations because `EOF` is less than 0, so the loop termination condition is already satisfied before the first iteration.

Comment: As for dynamic memory allocation, nothing about structure types conflicts with that.

Comment: `fgets(tipo[i].postal, 60, fp);` is wrong, since the `postal` member of your struct has length `8`.